# Should I use Redux to avoid this infinite loop caused by the props?

Tags: reactjs, redux

A friend of mine is recreating this [TV shows guide](http://www.movistarplus.es/programacion-tv/) with React.

Right now he has a prop like **moveScrollPosition** that handles the scroll when you move the hour scroll. It passes down the prop and moves the guide of the TV shows. The problem comes when you move the programs and it calls the same prop. The programs position moves AND calls the prop to move the guide. There is an infinite loop there, since the hour scroll calls the prop to move the TV shows.

Should he use Redux to store a global scroll position outside? This way both the hour scroll and the TV Shows scroll will call the action and update the scroll position. The TV Shows won't call the same prop, just rely on the prop from Redux as wel as the hour scroll.

To clarify:

1) Hour selector --> Props --> TV Shows

2) TV Shows --> Props --> Hour scroll --> Props --> TV Shows --> loop

Regards.

Comment: One possible cause of Infinite loop could be typically an attempt to update the state app during the render, so within a render method. Can you post your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't necessarily have to be redux.

In general you need some parent component maintaing the state (scroll position) that would be passed to children as props. It would also need a function to update the scroll position. This function would also be passed as prop to both child components. Whenever child components update the scroll, parent component will have state updated and will pass new value as props to children.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you need to implements guards to prevent async calls to the backend.

If u call the backend in a `componentDidMount` or `componentWillReceiveProps` you may get a rerender when the result comes in,  this can lead to a new call to that async method. If there is no guard, you may go into an endless loop.